# $\int_0^c f(x)dx=0$ for each $c\in[0,1]$ then $f=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be  *continuous* and $$\int_0^c f(x)dx =0$$ then  prove  that $f\equiv 0$.*Do  not  assume  that  $f\ge 0$.*

How  do  I  do  it $?$ . I  have  this  slightly  geometric  idea .

Fix $c\in [0,1]$ . Let  there  is $d\in [0,c]$  such that $f(d)\gt 0$. Then  by  continuity of  $f$ , there  is  a  non empty  neighbourhood  of  $d$  say  $U$  s.t  $f(x)\gt 0$  $\forall x\in U$. Consider  $\bar U\cap [0,c]$ . Then  this  must  be  an  interval of  form  $[p,c]$ or  $[p,v]$  s.t for  the  first  case , $$f(p)=0$$  and  if  the  second  case  happens  then  $$f(p)=0\\f(v)=0$$

Since  $$\int_0^c f(x)dx=0$$ ,  there  must  be  another  interval  in  $[0,c]$  say, $[a,b]$  s.t $$\int_p^{v(/c)} f(x)dx= -\int_a^b f(x)dx $$
And  also $f(x)\ge 0$
  cannot  hold  for  all  $x\in [a,b]$.

Now  *wlg*  assume  that $a\lt p$  then  consider the  interval  $[0,a]$ . The  same  thing  keeps  happening. So  with  my assumption  that  $f$ *is not identically $0$ over $[0,1]$*  ,  change  of  sign  of  the  graph  of  $f(x)$   inevitably  happens .

So ,  let $q$  be  the  first  point  where  $f$  first  changes  its  sign . Then $f(q)=0$  and  in the  interval $[0,q]$  $$\int_0^q f(x)dx \neq  0$$  and  thus  we  have  a  contradiction .

Hence  our  assumption  is  wrong  and  $f$  must   be  *identically*  $0$  all  over  $[0,1]$.
[image]

So ,  is  this   idea  effective  and  is  my  proof  correct  $?$  And  how  can  this  be  written  analytically  $?$

Thanks .

Comment: Let $g(c) = \int_0^c f(x) \; dx$. Then, $g$ is constant and thus $g' = f$ is zero...

Comment: @user251257 : thanks  .  that  is  a  very  nice  one.

Comment: If you don't have the fundamental theorem yet, to proof $g' = f$ you need that $f$ is continuous

Comment: your proof isn't correct. The interval $[a,b]$ need not to exist, neither need $q$ to exist.

Answer (score 2):

A far shorter proof :

Define the function :

$F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt$

By hypothesis, $\forall x \in [0,1], F(x) = 0$ : $F$ is the null function.

But as $f$ is continuous, we can use the fundamental theorem of calculus, to get that $f = F'$. So $f = 0$

Comment: This  is  far  shorter  and  far  nicer  proof .  But  is  my  approach/method  correct $?$

Comment: @user118494 : your general approach is indeed correct

Comment: @Tryas : OK . I  don't  know at  what  point  exactly   but  I  have  some  doubts  that  some  minor  details  went  wrong  with  that  or  it  is  not  perfectly  explained in  the  proof  I  wrote . Would  be  really  helpful  if  it  were  verified  and  corrected.

Comment: @user118494 : I'll write a (hopefully correct) version of your approach.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is a neater form :

Let $f \not \equiv 0$ a continuous function that verify the hypothesis.

There exists $c \in [0,1]$ such that $f(c) =M$

Without loss of generality, we can take $M>0$, and by continuity of $f$, $c\in]0,1[$

By continuity of $f$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\forall x \in [c-\delta,c+\delta], f(x) > \frac{M}{2}$.

Now, we have

$$\int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta} f(x) dx \geq \int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta} \frac{M}{2} dx = \delta M > 0$$

and

$$\int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta} f(x) dx = \int_0^{c+\delta} f(x) dx  - \int_0^{c-\delta} f(x) dx = 0-0 = 0$$

Hence the contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe your proof is quite correct as written. You say "let $q$ be the first point at which $f = 0$," but what does this mean? It's not automatic that there is a smallest such value. (For instance, there are continuous functions vanishing on all the $1/n$.)